# How can I render images from markdown to HTML in Astro using @astropub/md?

Tags: vite, astrojs

I'm working on a blog in Astro, and I'm trying to render the markdown from the blog post to HTML in using @astropub/md?

**Sample markdown blog post**

```
---
title: Sample image
meta:
  description: This is a simple post to say hello to the world.
pubDate: 2024-03-28
---

![an image](./images/mountain.jpeg)
```

**Blog overview Astro template**

```html
---
import { getCollection } from "astro:content";
import { Markdown } from "@astropub/md";


const allPosts = await getCollection("posts");
---

<ul>
  {
    allPosts.map((post: any) => (
      <li>
        <a href={`/blog/${post.slug}/`}>{post.data.title}</a>

        <Markdown of={post.body} />
      </li>
    ))
  }
</ul>
```

**The issue**

The image is only loading on the single blog post, not in the blog overview.
It's almost as if Vite isn't parsing images loaded through @astropub/md's  component.

Blog overview (doesn't load):

The `src` of the `img` tag is: `./images/mountain.jpeg`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0koj.png)

Blog post (works fine):

The `src` of the `img` tag is: `/_image?href=...`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL3tt.jpg)

Comment: If the markdown file is in the same repo as your astro project, you don't need `@astropub/md`. See https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/ instead. Regarding images, see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/

Comment: @mb21 how do I access the post body inside of a loop in the blog overview? that's where I am stuck

Comment: To keep it very simple, you don't even have to use collections. See e.g. https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorial/5-astro-api/1/#dynamically-display-a-list-of-posts (then you can use `(await Astro.glob('../pages/posts/*.md')).map(post => post.Content)`)
To use collections, see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/#rendering-content-to-html

Comment: @mb21 thank you for your answers :) however, they don’t solve the issue of Vite picking up on images within markdown in the blog overview.

When iterating through the posts via a loop or `map` (via a collection or straight markdown using the Astro.glob), the images will always be broken in the blog overview. Especially when you run `astro run build`.

Images in markdown only render in a single blog post template. I can’t get it to work in a loop, and have the images being transformed with Astro’s underlaying Vite. The url paths are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@astropub/md`, you can use the Content Collections API to render your content. For example:

```
---
import { getCollection } from "astro:content";

const allPosts = await getCollection("posts");
---

<ul>
  {
    allPosts.map(async (post) => {
      const { Content } = await post.render()

      return (
        <li>
          <a href={`/blog/${post.slug}/`}>{post.data.title}</a>
          <Content />
        </li>
      )
    })
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Any idea on how you can truncate the markdown within <Content />? Can you change it's content?

I plan on using https://github.com/pchiwan/markdown-truncate

Comment: Update: I fixed it by using `await Astro.glob('../pages/posts/*.md'))` rather than `getCollection`. Somehow Astro only picks up images when directly importing the markdown files.